# How can I prevent creating log files by CronJob?

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I have a Cronjob. My command is that: `wget mysite.com/bot.php` But this command will automatically creates log files that names are like:

- bot.php
- bot.php.1
- bot.php.2
- bot.php.3
- etc...

How can I prevent this?

Thanks!

Comment: Those are not the log files, but the content you requested. If you don't want it to be ever stored on disk, use [piping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) to pass the payload to other programs without intermediate storage. By the way, what does this question have to do with PHP, CPanel, cron and programming at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're trying to run your script without storing any information locally.

Try adding `&> /dev/null` to the end of your cron command, this will dump the output to /dev/null which is basically a black hole ( anything that ends up here is irretrievable ).

An example cron command would be:

```
*/5 * * * * wget -qO- http://example.com/check &> /dev/null
```

Comment: I could prevent my server from getting slower due to tons of cron log files using this solution. Thanks a lot!